# Calling a private method within another class into a class

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to call method within the BasicInfo class (full name(), alsoKnownAs()) into another class called Customer, specifically within the displayInfo() portion, but am not sure how to do that, here is my code:

```
enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE}

class BasicInfo
{
    private String firstName, secondName, lastName;
    private Gender g;
    
    //Default Constructor
    public BasicInfo()
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
    
    //Other Constructor
    public BasicInfo(String firstName, String secondName, String lastName, Gender g)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.g = g;
    }
    
    //Copy Constructor
    public BasicInfo(BasicInfo bi)
    {
        this.firstName = bi.firstName;
        this.secondName = bi.secondName;
        this.lastName = bi.lastName;
        this.g = bi.g;
    }
    
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    
    public String getSecondName()
    {
        return secondName;
    }
    
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    
    private Gender getGender()
    {
        return g;
    }
    
    public void setInfo(String firstName, String secondName, String lastName, Gender g)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.g = g;
    }
    
    private String fullName()
    {
        return (firstName + " " + secondName + " " + lastName);
    }
    
    private String alsoKnownAs()
    {
        return (firstName.charAt(0) + ". " + secondName.charAt(0) + ". " + lastName);
    }
    
    public void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.printf("Full name: %s%n", fullName());
        System.out.printf("Also known as: %s%n", alsoKnownAs());
        System.out.printf("Gender: %s%n", getGender());
    }
}

class Customer
{
    private BasicInfo bi;
    private int birthYear;
    
    public Customer()
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
    
    public Customer(BasicInfo bi, int birthYear)
    {
        this.bi = bi;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }
    
    public Customer(Customer c)
    {
        this.bi = c.bi;
        this.birthYear = c.birthYear;
    }
    
    public BasicInfo getBasicInfo()
    {
        return bi;
    }
    
    public int getBirthYear()
    {
        return birthYear;
    }
    
    public void setInfo(BasicInfo bi, int birthYear)
    {
        this.bi = bi;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }
    
    public void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.printf("Full name: %s%n", bi.fullName());
        System.out.printf("Also known as: %s%n", bi.alsoKnownAs());
        System.out.printf("Gender: %s%n", bi.getGender());
        System.out.printf("Year of birth: %d%n", birthYear);
    }
}
```

Within customer class, displayInfo(), I used "bi.fullName()" and "bi.alsoKnownAs()" and "bi.getGender()", is this the right way to method call? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I tried using "BasicInfo.'the method'" as well, but still resulted in a compilation error.

Comment: Why are those methods private? And no, this is not the correct way to call private methods and your compiler surely tells you so as well.

Comment: `private` means that this element (the method in your case) is basically only know to the class it is defined in. So other classes should by definition not have access to it - and if you need that to be changed then change the access modifier to something other than `private` (nothing aka package-private, `protected` or `public` depending on who should be able to access the method).

Answer (score 0):

This is against Java principles. If a method is designed to be called outside of its class then it cannot be `private`.

Comment: Okay, how do I then access methods within the BasicInfo class, in order to print "fullName()" for example in the Customer class's displayInfo() method? Sorry I'm quite new to this.

Comment: I guess you need to learn Java first. Get some book. Like "Thinking in Java". In case of this particular question: make the method `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change access specifier of this methods to protected/public or default as the private method can be accessed only within the current class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for taking the time to read my post.

```
    public void displayInfo()
{
    System.out.printf("Full name: %s%n", bi.fullName());
    System.out.printf("Also known as: %s%n", bi.alsoKnownAs());
    System.out.printf("Gender: %s%n", bi.getGender());
    System.out.printf("Year of birth: %d%n", birthYear);
}
```

I changed the above to this:

```
    public void displayInfo()
{
    bi.displayInfo();
    System.out.printf("Year of birth: %d%n", birthYear);
}
```

Which displayed the information from the BasicInfo class's displayInfo() method. Perhaps my question wasn't very clear in the first place. Instead of asking how to access a private method, I should have asked how to call displayInfo() method from the BasicInfo class into the Customer class.